# How can I draw the digital modulator by using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing the digital modulator like that may simply map the binary digit 0 into a waveform s0(t) and the binary digit 1 into a waveform s1(t).
Please see my figure as below

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not quite easy to see your figure clearly. You ought to draw such figure on GeoGebra or Word, etc., and take a screen shot, instead of doing like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a cute question, although I am not sure that I have exactly the output that you want. I decided to implement the last sketch in the OP. The other variations are easy modifications.

The code below defines a macro `\BinaryDigits` that accepts a comma separated list of `0`'s and `1`'s and then produces output like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\BinaryDigits[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8mm,scale=0.5]
      \draw(0.5,0)--++(0.5,0);
      \foreach \d [count=\c, remember=\c as \C] in {#1} {
         \ifnum\d=1 \draw(\c,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
         \else \draw(\c,0) rectangle ++(1,-1);
         \fi
         \node at (\c+0.5,1.5){\d};
      }
      \draw(\C+1,0)--+(0.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

  \BinaryDigits{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}

  \BinaryDigits{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a variation that draws only the path. It's interesting because to get the path to be continuous it seems easiest to put the `\foreach` inside the `\draw` command:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\BinaryDigits[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8mm,scale=0.5]
  \draw(0.5,0)--++(0.5,0)
     \foreach \d [count=\c, remember=\c as \C, evaluate=\d as \D using {int(2*\d-1)}] in {#1}
          { --(\c,\D)--++(1,0) } --(\C+1,0)--++(0.5,0);
     \foreach \d [count=\c] in {#1} {\node at (\c+0.5,0){$\d$};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  \BinaryDigits{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}

  \bigskip

  \BinaryDigits{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0}

\end{document}
```